# asp.net Control visibility

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a aspx form in which there are 5 controls below is the design code:

```
Question 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
Answer 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="If Other" AutoPostBack="True" 
  OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

A user selects a question from the drop down list and chooses the answer from the answer list.
If he/she doesn't find the answer in drop down list than he/she selects the checkbox and type the answer in textbox and press the submit button afterwards.

Is it possible to show the textbox and at the same time hide the drop down list using a single line code in checkbox `OnCheckedChanged` event?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (though I'd use some more lines for better readability), you should set the visibility of the `TextBox` to false, to hide it at first:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

In `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged`, you add the following lines:

```
DropDownList2.Visible = !CheckBox1.Checked;
TextBox1.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
```

Comment: Appreciate your response sir and thanks for fixing my question as well, but I only want to use a single line code like a toggle or something if you are getting my request

Comment: Why does it matter if we use a a tiny, small amount of code (2 lines). Are you trying to save money, and expect one extra line of code to break your software budget here, and expect that super small saving of one line of code to save world poverty or some such? I am REALLY struggling to figure out why 1 tiny extra line of code, and 2 lines of code in place of one line would EVER matter here? Can't be performance, can't be blowing out your developer budgets. Is there some other really amazing and good reason for only wanting to use 1 line of code vs 2 lines? Why? and why would one care?

Comment: no money is involved in this task it's a task given to me by my mentor/teacher last night I tried everything in my hand but couldn't find the solution for it that's why I posted the question here hoping someone give me the desired answer for the question

Comment: AFAIK toggling both controls in the same line is not possible because of the negation (`DropDownList2` should be visible when `TextBox1` isn't). You can toggle each one of them on one line (e.g. `DropDownList2.Visible = !DropDownList2.Visible;`). However, I'd use the approach above that relies on `CheckBox1.Checked` because this asserts that the state of the checkbox is respected.